# Laravel4 not installing correctly

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to install Laravel4 in a ubuntu.
But each time I try to make it work following the install instructions, I receive an error in the php pages.
Any ideas where I should look for?
After clean install, when I launch the site I receive this error :

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /mnt/hgfs/www/......./vendor/patchwork/utf8/bootup.utf8.php on line 309`

Answer (score 0):

I got some troubles too. The probem I had come from the fact the entire project files do not had correct rigths.

Try this in your root application folder:

> find ./ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} + && find ./ -type f -exec chmod
>   664 {} +

Hope it helps.